# XMVECTOR weird values

Tags: c++, vector, graphics, directx, directx-12

Starting out with DirectX and messing around with XMVECTORs

(I know I don't use them in context, I'm just curious)

```
// Vectors.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <DirectXMath.h>
#include <DirectXPackedVector.h>


int main()
{
    using namespace DirectX;

    XMVECTOR vector = XMVectorSet(1, 2, 3, 1);

    int x = XMVectorGetIntX(vector);

    std::cout << "vector.x: " << x << std::endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

This prints a value of **1065353216**

Whilst interesting, I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong, or if this is indeed the intended functionality.

Comment: You should use `XMVectorSetInt` if you want to store integer data.

Comment: `1065353216` is `0x3F800000` in hex, what is IEEE754 representation of 1.0f.

Comment: Ah I see! So what's the intended use of XMVectorSet then?

Comment: Everything not suffixed with *Int is for floating point data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying SIMD instructions are typeless. You can treat the same data as 4 floats or as 4 integers (or 8 shorts or 16 bytes). DirectXMath usually works with 4 floats, which is what your `XMVECTOR` is getting from `XMVectorSet`.

If you used `float x = XMVectorGetX(vector);` you'd get "1.0" back.

Alternatively, you could have used `XMVECTOR vector = XMVectorSetInt(1, 2, 3, 1);`

See [DirectXMath Programmer's Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dxmath/ovw-xnamath-progguide) as well as the [GitHub project](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath/).